# Possible improvements for an OO PHP written script

Tags: php, oop, csv

Okay, I am wanting to expand my armoury within PHP, so I've been researching OO PHP. With my researched knowledge I went on to create a quick script that reads a CSV file and outputs the results.

CSV Class:

```
class CSV {

    private $file; 

    public function __construct($filename, $mode) {
        $this->file = fopen($filename, $mode); 
    }

    public function endFile() {
        return feof($this->file); 
    }

    public function getCSV($mode) {
        return fgetcsv($this->file, $mode);
    } 

    public function close() {
        fclose($this->file); 
    }
}
```

The test file:

```
require('class.csv.php');

$csv = new CSV('postcodes.csv', 'r'); 

while(!$csv->endFile()) {

    $postcode = $csv->getCSV(1024); 
    echo $postcode[0] . "<br />"; 

}

$csv->close();
```

I am just wondering if there are... or what are the improvements I could make in regards to the OO approach. This is purely a script for me to put the knowledge i've learnt together. I'm not another 'following the crowd person' who creates every script in an OO approach because they 'can'.

I understand it is a short script but I am wanting to make sure I have the correct approach before moving forward.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a **code review request**. This is better suited to the [Code Review Stack Exchange site](http://codereview.stackexchange.com). Before posting there be sure to read their [FAQ](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help) to ensure that your question meets their guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

The only possibly thing I can think of that would *improve* the code is to have less in your main test file. A general idea of using object-oriented code is that you can do a lot with the class itself and less in the main file.

So for example, say you needed to do exactly what you're doing in the test file again later on in the code. You would need to complete duplicate the while loop again. Instead, maybe write a method that handles the algorithm your while loop is doing and call that instead. Then later on, you could just call that method again and it's that simple!

The best part is, you can use the methods from your class inside other methods in the class. Like the `endFile()` method could be called from another method by saying `$this->endFile()` the same way that you are calling `$file` by saying `$this->file`

Otherwise, I'd say you're looking good!